# Pre .NET 4 memory cache

Tags: c#, .net, caching, memorycache

I want to use the new MemoryCache class but I am not yet using .NET 4. I do have a simple cache class (internally uses a dictionary). What would be a good approach in using this class like the MemoryCache? Does anyone know how MemoryCache is managed throughout the lifetime of an application (non asp.net)?

Comment: are we talking about a multithreaded application? as that would make things a lot more complicated

Comment: Whats wrong with your class that uses a dictionary internally? That's how I usually do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a tool like Structuremap for that? It's not really meant to do these things (it's a DI container) but it will work out well if you specify some items as a singleton, some items on a request basis etc. It just depends on how granular you want the lifetime management to be.

Comment: Couldn't I just make the Cache class a singleton without using a DI tool?

Comment: You can but that will not solve you're lifecycle management problems. Making it a singleton will make all you objects last forever.

Comment: it will make the cache last the lifetime of the app, which is what I want. Am I missing something? The exe has a short lifespan - 1-2 minutes per execution

Comment: Make it a singleton, no doubt about it.

Answer (score 1):

[Enterprise Library](https://entlib.codeplex.com/) had a Caching block that was similar to what .Net 4 has now on the core framework.

It was there for Version 5, but I think it has been removed from version 6. Getting an older version of the enterprise library will provide you with a caching mechanism.